# Написал простой туннель, не работает передача данных выше 1400 байт

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tunnel

Код на сервере и клиенте одинаковый, при запросе/ответе размером выше ~1400 байт перестает работать корректно: пинг не работает, http тоже...

Код:

```
//config tun

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('172.16.0.2', 9090))
print('Connected')

def writen() :
    while 1 :
        buf = tun.read(1420)
        sock.send(buf)

def readn() :
        while 1 :
                buf = sock.recv(1420)
                tun.write(buf)

//threads
```

Comment: что такое `tun`?

Comment: обратите внимание, операции send и write возвращают количество записанных байт и оно может быть меньше того что вы хотели записать. данные необходимо буферизировать и досылать позже то, что сразу не записалось. Кроме того, надо так же понимать, что recv имеет полное право прочитать за один раз не столько же данных, сколько было одномоментно записано. Получаемые данные так же надо буферизировать и быть готовым к дочитыванию не достающих. И да, MTU (максимальный размер пакета) обычно 1500 байт, часть занимают заголовки. И при его превышении данные наверняка будут получаться частями

Comment: А почему ОС не генерирует пакеты под MTU сама???

Comment: Видимо вы ниже по стеку, поэтому всё в ваших руках.